# Illegal type error when using Integer as argument

Tags: haskell

Beginner trying to do the 99 problems. Here is my attempt to solve the third problem (yes):

```
elementAt :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
elementAt _ x | x <= 0 = Nothing
elementAt [] x | x > 0 = Nothing
elementAt (x: _) 1 = Just x
elementAt (_: xs) x | x > 1 = elementAt xs (x-1)

testElementAt :: IO ()
testElementAt = do
    print (elementAt []::[Int] 5)
    print (elementAt []::[Int] 0)
    print (elementAt [1, 2, 3] 2)
    print (elementAt [1, 2, 3] 5)
    print (elementAt [1, 2, 3] 1)
    print (elementAt [1, 2, 3] 0)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    testElementAt
```

Error message:

```
error:
    Illegal type: ‘5’ Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds
        print (elementAt []::[Int] 5)
                                   ^
```

I guess it has something to do with `5` being able to be Int as well as Float? (Just like `[]` which I have to type it with `::[Int]` to pass the compiler?) However, the same trick does not seem to work.

What should I do?

Comment: `5` is part of the type signature.

Comment: Without parentheses, `elementAt []::[Int] 5` is parsed as `elementAt []::([Int] 5)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`5` is here part of the type signature. If you want to specify the type of the list, you do that with:

```
print (elementAt ([] :: [Int]) 5)
```

here we thus give a type hint that the empty list is a list of `Int`s. The `5` in this case is thus seen as the second parameter.

Comment: Thank you. But I tried this. But without the space. Now it worked. :)) (I heard about the space-sensitivity, but not expected to be this sensitive :))

Comment: @ClémentDato: what do you mean with "*without the space*"?

Comment: I did it like `print (elementAt ([]::[Int]) 5)`

Comment: @ClémentDato: well the spaces before and after the `::` are optional, so that does not matter. What matters is that you use parenthesis to make sure the type signature is applied to `[]`, and that `5` is not seen as a type parameter.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. I can not replicate the no-space error any more. Maybe it's just some of my unintended beginner side effect (forgetting to save before compiling).